# Null Byte appending while reading the file through Python pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv

I have created a script which will give you the match rows between the two files. Post that, I am returning the output file to a function, which will be used the file as input to create pivot using pandas.

But somehow, something seems to be wrong, below is the code snippet

```
def CreateSummary(file):
    out_file = file
    file_df = pd.read_csv(out_file) ## This function is appending NULL Bytes at 
                                      the end of the file
    #print file_df.head(2)
```

The above code is giving me the error as

```
   ValueError: No columns to parse from file
```

Tried another approach:

```
  file_df = pd.read_csv(out_file,delim_whitespace=True,engine='python')

  ##This gives me error as
      _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Any suggestions and criticism is highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know it's a NULL byte?

Comment: Because I can see in the file itself, and also the error also says so..

Comment: Please use the preview window before posting, and note that Markdown code blocks need a blank line before them to work correctly.